# How to add a Valid and trusted security certificate for my website in my iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, ssl-certificate, web-clips

It is a HTTPS site.

I want to add a webclip to my iphone but it shows an annoying screenshot when not connected to vpn. On connecting it shows my webclip perfectly. Android adding to home screen works perfectly with/without vpn. On researching a lot and tearing apart my hair i found out that untrusted certificates in ios might be an issue. Could any help me as to how to add and trust my web app. Am i missing something? I am basically a novice so any help would be nice.

Comment: What did you find so far?

Comment: Password protection was an issue. So I hosted my . PNG file on a different non protected site and accessed it from there and voila it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
- use another email account on the iPhone

- email the self signed (root) certificate to your mail account on the phone
- open the email and tap the attachment (cert)
- tap install on the top right hand corner and complete installation

Go back to Mail and Calendar settings to add your Exchange mail account. You should now be able to proceed.

From [The apple Guy](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7738477?start=0&tstart=0)